# Processing text file as blocks

Tags: perl

What is wrong with my code? My DATA has 4 blocks, but my code only prints result from first three blocks. The same result obtained when I read the data from a file.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.30.3;
use warnings;
my $sum=0;
my $block=1;

while(<DATA>){
    chomp(my $line = $_);
    if ($line !~ /^$/){
        $sum = $sum+$line;
    }else{
        say "Sum of block-${block}: $sum";
        $sum = 0;
        $block++;
    }
}

__DATA__
345
478

300
255
100

1200
1000
4000

182
347
611
714
```

The result printed:

```
Sum of block-1: 823
Sum of block-2: 655
Sum of block-3: 6200
```

Comment: Because you print the sum when you see an empty line, but there is no empty line after the last block. Either add one, or print after the loop (maybe if `sum` is > 0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program prints the sum when it comes to an empty line but there is no extra line after the end of data.  One way to fix that is to also test for end-of-file, with [eof](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof).

With the program slightly rearranged

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $sum = 0;
my $block = 0;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;

    if ($line =~ /^$/ or eof DATA){
        ++$block;
        say "Sum of block-$block: $sum";
        $sum = 0;
    } else {
        $sum += $line;
    }
}

say "Read $block blocks";

__DATA___
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You exit the loop when there's no data left, and you don't print anything after the loop.

**Solution 1**: Print something after the loop

```perl
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp( $line );
    if ( $line =~ /^$/ ) {
        if ( defined( $sum ) ) {
            say "Sum of block-${block}: $sum";
            $sum = undef;
            ++$block;
        }

        next;
    }

    $sum += $line;
}

if ( defined( $sum ) ) {
    say "Sum of block-${block}: $sum";
}
```

**Solution 2**: Don't exit the loop so soon.

```perl
while ( 1 ) {
    my $line = <DATA>;
    if ( !defined( $line ) || $line =~ /^$/ ) {
        if ( defined( $sum ) ) {
            say "Sum of block-${block}: $sum";
            $sum = undef;
            ++$block;
        }

        if ( defined( $line ) ) {
            next;
        } else {
            last;
        }
    }

    chomp( $line );
    $sum += $line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code outputs only when you have a line with no data (there is no any validation for input data).

Sum of last data block will be printed out only if input data have last line with no data.

Study following sample code which is a slight modification of original code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $sum=0;
my $block=1;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    $sum += $1 if /(\d+)/;
    if( /^\s*$/ && $sum ) {
        say "Sum of block-${block}: $sum";
        $sum = 0;
        $block++;
    }
}

say "Sum of block-${block}: $sum" if $sum;

exit 0;

__DATA__
345
478

300
255
100

1200
1000
4000

182
347
611
714
```

Output

```
Sum of block-1: 823
Sum of block-2: 655
Sum of block-3: 6200
Sum of block-4: 1854
```

There is a better way to make computation on input data of this kind.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my(@blocks,$count,%sum);

@blocks = do { local $/ = "\n\n"; <DATA> };

for my $block ( @blocks ) {
    ++$count;
    $sum{$count} += $_ for $block =~ /(\d+)/gsm;
}

say "Sum of block $_: $sum{$_}" for sort keys %sum;

exit 0;

__DATA__
345
478

300
255
100

1200
1000
4000

182
347
611
714
```

Output

```
Sum of block 1: 823
Sum of block 2: 655
Sum of block 3: 6200
Sum of block 4: 1854
```

Comment: Your first snippet doesn't print sums of zero. Both of your snippets handle errors worse than the OP's code (which warns on bad data).

Comment: @ikegami how will react OP's code if there are several empty lines between blocks? How the code will react if instead of digits will be a words?

Comment: Re "*how will react OP's code if there are several empty lines between blocks?*", Several empty line in a row doesn't mean several empty lines between blocks. It could indicate the presence of empty blocks. The current code behaves as if they are empty blocks and sensibly prints a sum of zero for them. /// Re "*How the code will react if instead of digits will be a words?*" Did you not read the comment to which you are replying? Like I said,  it handles it well. It's your code that handles it poorly. You made things *worse*.

Comment: Re "*Is OP specifies that two lines are an empty block in his post?*", No, why do you ask? Do you think they did? This is the second question you ask about this, with no point in sight. If you have a point to make, please make it.

Comment: Re "*I gave a direction and not final solution.*", If so, your directions point in the wrong way. You also made things worse, so I mentioned it. Because you should have and you didn't.